# Type '{ type: any; required: [true, string]; unique: true; match: (string | RegExp)[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, authentication, mongoose

I'm using nodejs and typescript to build a user model. In my mongoose model I'm trying to add a match property to the email field of the Schema but I keep getting this typescript error.:

```
Argument of type '{ firstName: { type: any; required: [true, string]; }; lastName: { type: any; required: [true, string]; }; email: { type: any; required: [true, string]; unique: true; match: (string | RegExp)[]; }; password: { ...; }; role: { ...; }; resetPasswordToken: any; resetPasswordExpire: DateConstructor; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SchemaDefinition'.
  Property 'email' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ type: any; required: [true, string]; unique: true; match: (string | RegExp)[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string | Function | Function[] | Schema<Document<any>, Model<Document<any>>> | SchemaDefinition | SchemaTypeOptions<any> | Schema<Document<any>, Model<Document<any>>>[] | SchemaTypeOptions<...>[] | SchemaDefinition[]'.
      Type '{ type: any; required: [true, string]; unique: true; match: (string | RegExp)[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

This is the model file:

**user.ts**

```
import mongoose, { Model, Schema } from 'mongoose';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import User from '../interfaces/User';


const userSchema: Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String, 
        required: [true, 'Please enter a first name']
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter a last name']
    },
    email: {
        type: String, 
        required: [true, 'Please enter an email'],
        unique: true,
        match: [
            /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/,
            'Please add a valid email'
        ]
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a password'],
        minlength: 6,
        select: false
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['admin', 'customer'],
        default: 'customer'
    },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpire: Date
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

userSchema.pre<User>('save', async function(next) {
    if (!this.isModified('password')) {
        next();
    }
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});

userSchema.methods.getSignedJwtToken = function(next: any) {
    // @ts-ignore
    return jwt.sign({id: this._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES});
};

userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function(enteredPassword: string) {
    // @ts-ignore
    return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
};

userSchema.methods.getResetPasswordToken = function() {
    const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
    // @ts-ignore
    this.resetPasswordToken = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(resetToken).digest('hex');
    // @ts-ignore
    this.resetPasswordExpire = Date.now() + 10 * 60 * 1000;
    return resetToken;
}

export default mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And this is the interface I'm using:

**User.ts**

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export default interface User extends Document {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    email: string,
    password: string,
    role: string,
    resetPasswordToken: string,
    resetPasswordExpire: Date
}
```

I noticed the error comes when I add the match property to the email object.

Comment: The term `string` (note the casing) refers only to a type, not a value.

Comment: I later noticed that and tried it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

In `getResetPasswordToken` add `this.save()` before `return resetToken`

Answer (score -1):

For mongoose schemas, you should use `capitalized` version of [String](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#strings),which is an actual value type in [javascript String Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), and should not be confused with the [typescript primitive string type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#string).